# How to fix R6031 - Attempt to initialize the CRT more than once. This indicates a bug in your application?

Tags: c++, c, windows

When I clicked on some of my Windows Program, it gives me this error:

[image]

What causes this error?

And how do I fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I tried to follow this solution: https://support.accessdata.com/hc/en-us/articles/203776985--R6031-Attempt-to-initialize-the-CRT-more-than-once-This-indicates-a-bug-in-your-application-

Comment: In my regedit, under Windows I could not find AppCompatFlags\Layers..where can I find it?

Comment: You are better to look on microsoft support forums. This isn't a programming related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173740.aspx

In short, just repair/reinstall it.

Comment: thank you @WenQin I will do so

Comment: it's a bit weird..i just restarted twice..and i don't get the error anymore